# context in main method in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'd like my app loads all the localization strings before showing the first page. To get a translated string I use this instruction:
`MyLocalizations.of(context).trans('key')`

In all other pages works but in main doesn't. I'd like to have the localized string without give the context variable. How could I do?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I need to do this because I have a list of variable that contains translations and want them to be initialized once. If I put them in build or didupdatewidget they will be initialized multiple times.

Comment: You can't get the context in the main method because it doesn't exist yet. You're going to need a way to initialize it without the context or initialize it during the `initState` of the root widget.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in `main`? Show a complete app code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a naive way on how I managed to solve this problem.

*Pseudocode:*

```
@override
void initState() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    initializeVarWithTranslation(context);       // the initialization with translation
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(varWithTranslation==null)
     return SizedBox();    //If it yet is not initialized I show nothing or a splashscreen
  return Scaffold( ... );  //My page
}
```